# conditional skipping of the files using pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access

I am trying to read the values in the columns which I would like to use from the database files such as MS Access file only if the certain condition are met.

I have 26 different MS access files representing the database for 26 different years.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
k = 1993 + np.arange(24)

for i in k:
    print(i)
    DBfile = r'D:\PMIS1993_2016'+'\\'+str(i)+'\\pmismzxpdata_'+str(i)+'.mdb'
    print(DBfile)
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    qry = "SELECT JCP_FAILED_JNTS_CRACKS_QTY, JCP_FAILURES_QTY, JCP_SHATTERED_SLABS_QTY, JCP_LONGITUDE_CRACKS_QTY, JCP_PCC_PATCHES_QTY FROM PMIS_JCP_RATINGS WHERE BEG_REF_MARKER_NBR = '0342' and BEG_REF_MARKER_DISP LIKE '0.5' and RATING_CYCLE_CODE = 'P'"
    dataf = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
    print(dataf)
    D = list(dataf.values[0])
    print(D)

    conn.close()
```

Here I have tried to read values of variables of JCP_FAILED_JNTS_CRACKS_QTY, JCP_FAILURES_QTY, JCP_SHATTERED_SLABS_QTY and  JCP_LONGITUDE_CRACKS_QTY, JCP_PCC_PATCHES_QTY  when BEG_REF_MARKER_NBR = '0342' and BEG_REF_MARKER_DISP LIKE '0.5' and RATING_CYCLE_CODE = 'P'.

However, not every year meets the conditions of BEG_REF_MARKER_NBR = '0342' and BEG_REF_MARKER_DISP LIKE '0.5' and RATING_CYCLE_CODE = 'P'.

So, I would like to skip the years which does not meet these condition such as if else function indicating the years which does not satisfy.

If you have any help or idea, I would really appreciate.

Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) attribute:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame().empty  # This DataFrame has no rows
Out[11]: True
```

e.g. to skip the empty `dataf`s:

```
if not dataf.empty:
    D = list(dataf.values[0])
    print(D)
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, I really appreciate your help.